# How to clear the resources used by the fragment while we destroy the activity?

Tags: xamarin.android

For example, I have added the TextView inside the fragment as below.

```
        var adaptor = new GenericFragmentPagerAdaptor(SupportFragmentManager); // where GenericFragementPagerAdaptor is a sub-class derived from FragementPagerAdaptor

        adaptor.AddFragmentView((i, v, b) => {
            var view = i.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tab, v, false);
            textView = new TextView(view.Context);
            textView.Text = "Test1";
            view.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.mainFrame).AddView(textView);
            return view;
```

If I am destroying the current activity means, all the resources related to the fragment should be cleared.Where and how can I do that? Please, anyone suggests me.

Comment: How does this differ from other resources which need to be released when no longer needed in C# (I assume it is C#)? Those use cases are solved by making a class which implements IDisposable and using it inside a `using` block, and possibly providing a suitable destructor.

Comment: I mean the view used inside the fragment is the resource here. I have tried by implementing IDisposable and it did not work

Comment: Ok, "did not work" is not very specific, and you do not provide code. Apart from Sachin's advice which is perhaps the proper thing to do (use callbacks/events provided by the class when its life cycle state changes) you can implement a `Dispose()` method which "clears the resources related to the fragment", whatever those are (the view here) and whatever "clearing" entails. Of course the `Dispose()` function must be called explicitly or implicitly at the end of a `using` block. What exactly did not work?

Comment: I was able to understand your solution that if I call the dispose, the resources used will clear. but my doubt is, how can I able to get the resources or view used in the fragment? Once I get it, then I will clear in the dispose method or other destroy methods.

Comment: Some of the "resources" will probably be accessible through members of the object being disposed (I guess that `textView` is a member variable?). If you must dispose of the `view` which is  the result of `i.Inflate()` but that result is not stored or accessible anywhere, it is your job to memorize it, for example in an additional member of your derived class. The only purpose is to have it ready for disposal at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks,

Before destroying an activity(onDestroy()), fragment's life cycle methods onDestroyView() and onDetach() will be called.

onDestroyView() -> Tells the fragment that its view is being destroyed so that it can clean up any associated resources.

My suggestion is to once download this example and explore all the life cycle methods of fragment.

https://github.com/SilverBayTech/FragmentLifeCycle.

If any further help is needed, I would be grateful to help you.

In a Fragment with UI you often save some Views as instance state to speed up access. For example a link to your EditText so you don't have to findViewById it all the time.

The problem is that a View keeps a reference to the Activity context. Now if you retain a View you also retain a reference to that context.

That is no problem if the context is still valid but the typical retain case is restarting the Activity. Very often for a screen rotation for example. Activity recreation will create a new context and old contexts are intended to be garbage collected. But it can't be garbage collected now since your Fragment still has a reference to the old one.

Following example shows how not to do it

public class LeakyFragment extends Fragment {

```
private View mLeak; // retained

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLeak = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever, container, false);
    return mLeak;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    // not cleaning up.
}
```

}

To get rid of that problem, you need to clear all references to your UI in onDestroyView. Once the Fragment instance is re-used you will be asked to create a new UI on onCreateView. There is also no point in keeping the UI after onDestroyView. The Ui is not going to be used.

The fix in this example is just changing onDestroyView() method.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    mLeak = null; // now cleaning up!
}
```

And besides keeping references to Views you should obviously not keep references to the Activity (e.g. from onAttach - clean on onDetach) or any Context (unless it's the Application context).

Comment: I have analyzed the sample, but I couldn't get it. Please tell how to intimate the fragment that its view is being destroyed?

Comment: I have just edited my answer by showing  a simple example. Please take a reference from that. Let me know this example clears your doubt.